# Limit the number of cin input on variable

Tags: c++, variables, input, cin

How do I limit the user input on the number of variable I want ?

ie

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main{

    char variable1, variable2, variable3;
    cin >> variable1 >> variable2 >> variable3;   
}
```

If the user input 2 3 4 5, i don't want the 4th value to go into the next input i have. Any idea?

I have tried using setw(10) to limit then but it seems doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different cins (separate ones) for example:

```
cin>>variable1;
cin>>variable2;
cin>>variable3;
```

This would prevent saving multiple variables and generate an error if a user types "4 5"

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of that. But is there any more special feature of C++ that can do the same thing too?

Comment: I have no knowledge of such function, hope my method helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite simple, but it's wholly doable.

You need to ensure that your program stops reading the input stream after it gets the first 3 inputs, separated by whitespaces. If you work with "getline(t, param, delim)" instead of just "cin", you'll have more options available to you. In a nutshell, getline is a function in the  library that lets you take (from_somewhere, to_somewhere, stop_reading_here). For you, you'll be reading in from the "cin" stream, so it should look something like this:

```
getline(cin, random_string_variable_name, ' ');
```

The third parameter, the delimiter, is a space between two apostrophes. It's telling the function that whatever it's read in through 'cin' ends when it gets to the first space. If you try this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string variable[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        getline(cin, variable[i], ' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << variable[i] << " ";

}
```

you'll find that "1 2 3 4 5" would return "1 2 3 ". Tell me if you need explanation on the square brackets or "for" loops, though you really should google that first if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

As you are writing "If the user input 2 3 4 5, i don't want the 4th value to go into the next input i have.", I think your main interest is not limiting the input, but avoiding negative effects from additional input. This can be achieved by reading the user input into one string and extraction the integers from the string:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    // parse line to extract the single numbers
    }
```